# Using Intel and NVIDIA Hardware-Encoders (QuickSync/ nvenc) simultaniously on Linux

Tags: nvidia, manjaro, intel, i915

I recently setup a new PC I intend to use for Video Encoding.
I'm running an new I-series processor with integrated graphics and a rtx3000 series NVIDIA card. I want to use the NVIDIA nvenc hardware encoder as well as Intel's Quick-sync.
My old PC already ran a NVIDIA GTX1000 series card and I reused my SSD with an existing Manjaro installation. The NVIDIA GPU worked out of the box with the proprietary NVIDIA driver. For the QSV encoder I tried following the Arch wiki Articles on [Hardware Acceleration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Hardware_video_acceleration#Configuring_VA-API) and [Intel Graphics](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/intel_graphics), but have not been successful so far.
The Mainboard (Gigabyte Z690UD) does not have any Display connectors for the Intel GPU.

```
vainfo
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
libva error: /usr/lib/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed
vaInitialize failed with error code 18 (invalid parameter),exit
```

> /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-mhwd.conf

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "intel"
    VendorName     "Intel Corporation"
EndSection
```

As shown below, lspci does not list a Kernel module loaded for the Intel GPU:

```
lspci -k | grep -A 3 VGA

0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation AlderLake-S GT1 (rev 0c)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device d000
0000:01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 [GeForce RTX 3090] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 3881
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

I manually added the Intel driver:

> /etc/modules-load.d/mhwd-gpu.conf

```
##
## Generated by mhwd - Manjaro Hardware Detection
##
i915
nvidia
nvidia-drm
```

and added it to:

> /etc/mkinitcpio.conf

```
MODULES="intel_agp i915 nvidia nvidia_modeset nvidia_uvm nvidia_drm"
```

I checked the modules blacklists, ran mkinitcpio and updated grub, but lspc still doesn't show a driver in use.
I don't really know where to go from here as I'm not too knowledgeable on inner workings of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is dead, but from a quick glance at the code, you're searching for incredibly old Intel drivers.

Back from when AGP was the graphics interconnect standard, and this entire generation of cards/gpu's did not support these acceleration features either (At least I can guarantee you the intel's did not have quicksync up until the Core 'i' line, post duo and quad).

I too, am currently seeking drivers for hardware encoding/acceleration for my i5-8365u which uses an Intel UHD 620 graphics chip. In terms of typical S/W acceleration I think I'm fine with the stock kernel and setup, but for OBS or anything else, I believe I will either need to modify some strings, or find a driver, likely both.

In YOUR case,

0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation AlderLake-S GT1 (rev 0c)
DeviceName: Onboard - Video
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device d000

We can see here, by the listing of your CPU type, Alder-Lake, that you indeed have a 12th gen Intel CPU. I believe intel uses the Iris Xe chips for graphics on those, and they are quite new still, but not new enough that software hasn't caught up to it. I hope...

According to a post, here - https://forum.manjaro.org/t/12th-gen-intel-driver-issues/135737

"mithrial - Mar 7
Please read the arch wiki entry for the Intel GPUs. Your device is too new and does not need or have any X configuration.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/intel_graphics 24

Without a detailed description of your system, there’s not much to go on for help."

I don't know if any of this will be helpful, but some X info can be found on this page here to view your channels for drivers.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xorg#Driver_installation

Supposedly through this digging, Intel is one of the largest contributors to the open-source display drivers found in linux-kernels, but there are other packages/options to try.